# Receiving "Access Denied" when calling WCF from jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, wcf

I've tried numerous ways to get jQuery to call a WCF service without an error, but with no luck. My WCF service is in a subdomain of the main site. I've tried adding the following before my ajax call:

```
jQuery.support.cors = true;
```

But I receive an '*Access Denied*' message. If I comment that out and use:

```
document.domain = "mylightdisplay.com";
```

I receive a '*No Transport*' message.

Anyone ever come across this and have a solution for circumventing these exceptions? It works when I have the main site local using localhost and I'm trying to connect to the web services on the remote server. When testing this scenario, I'm using Web Matrix.

Here's a code snippet as requested below:

```
function populateData() {
    $.support.cors = true;
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "http://mydomain.com/myservice.svc/GetInfo",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(msg) {
            ...
        },
        error: function (msg) {
            ...
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it! Had to add the following to the ajax call:

```
jsonpCallback: "MyMethodResult",
dataType: "jsonp",
```

Answer (score 0):

We need a lot more info than that, Mr. Gaylord.

Can you give us a full code snippet of the attempted connection, as well as the WCF method you are attempting to connect with?

In the meantime, check the subdomain issue. I know jQuery does not like cross-domain calls to web services because of XSS measures... JSONP is sometimes requried to get around that. I've not tried it with subdomains, but cross-domain it is definitely a problem.

Comment: I'll include a sample, but as I stated, the call works except for a subdomain call.

Comment: It's not a POST, so the cross-domain issue I mentioned shouldn't be an issue. I'm not sure about the No Transport error to be honest. whats the `.support.cors = true` bit for?

Comment: That allows cross-domain access. Even if I remove document.domain (which throws an exception anyway), I get a No transport message.